# Maya Python object assigned as a listType, but won't convert to string?

Tags: python, string, list, unicode, maya

I'm starting to use objects a bit more to store Maya commands in Python. This is super useful!

But I've run into a problem. Sometimes objects get commands that return Unicode lists rather than a string. Even using str() doesn't work.

Code:

```
cubeParent = cmds.polyCube(sx=10, sy=15, sz=5, h=20)

print cubeParent                # prints transform and shape node, but unicode list?
print str(cubeParent)           # prints transform and shape node, again unicode list?
print cubeParent[0]             # prints transform node with good formatting! yay!
```

Why is cubeParent assigned as a listType?

Comment: The default behavior for most node creation commands is to return two values: a transform and a shape node.  This is pretty standard throughout maya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert each item in the list to string datatype.

```
print list(map(str, cubeParent))
```

OR

```
print [str(i) for i in cubeParent]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this at the assignment level rather than the print level?

Comment: sure `m = list(map(str, cubeParent)); print m`

Answer (score 2):

for lurkers:  You can get the info you want with multiple assignments as well:

```
transform, shape = cmds.polyCube()
print transform
# 'pCube1'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer from Maya perspective IMO.